# how to get value of dynamic checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

In android phonegap application ,I created div with questions and options(chechbox) dynamically(each question have three or four checkbox).I have one submit button.

Now I want to get value of question and selected option while clicking the button.

How to do that?

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't describe checkboxes as options it is rather confusing since HTML *does* have an `<option>` element.

Comment: And do you mean "options" rather than "option"? The point of checkboxes is that zero or more can be picked (rather than exactly one, which is what radio buttons are for).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   var selected_values = new Array();
    $('#myform :checkbox').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked"))
          selected_values.push($(this).value)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the checked option

```
 $('#myform :checkbox').find(':checked').val();
```

or use filter instead :

```
$('#myform :checkbox').filter(':checked').val();
```

to get all values :

```
  var checkedOptions = new Array();

  $("#myform :checked").filter(':checked').each(function() {
      checkedOptions .push($(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: That will get only the value of the first checkbox that is checked. The question is asking for the values of multiple checkboxes.

Comment: `find` isn't going to work. The gets descendants that match, and checkboxes can't have descendants.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same thing. I tried the answer by Yorgo, but it was not working. It just required a small tweaking

```
var selected_values = new Array();
$('#myform :checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        selected_values.push($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

using

```
$(this).attr("value") instead of $(this).val();
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybuttonid').click(function(){
        var checkbox1 = $('#mycheckboxid1:checked').val();
        var checkbox2 = $('#mycheckboxid2:checked').val();
        ...
    }
}
```

will return true or false

Comment: No, it won't. It will return `undefined` or the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Umm. I just used your code. Since there wasn't a matching element on the page I tested with, I got `undefined` as the result.

Comment: replace myinputid for the id of your html checkbox, if you dont set it just put id="myinputid" on your checkbox html

Comment: After your edits … you are using the same element id for the checkbox and the submit button. That isn't going to work.

Comment: myinputid is the id of the checkbox, the code describe: when the html is ready do{ when the checkbox is clicked do{ lastcheckboxvalue get checkbox value }

Comment: This only tests a single checkbox and gives either its value or `undefined`. Since the question appears to be looking for the values of all the checkboxes that are checked, that won't solve the problem.

Comment: The question states that the click is on the submit button, not the checkbox.

Comment: If I have three question ,if it is two question is answered ,while clicking the submit button I get value of that two question.how to do that.please help me.

Comment: I think you are using checkbox in the wrong way, think about using radiobutton